# How to open a new slack channel with hubot

Tags: hubot, slack

I want to open a new channel on slack using hubot. The use case is straight forward. Hubot observes external events and in case of a certain events I want to open a new channel and and invite other users.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that once you have the correct api key setup, you just need to send a call to the following end point

```
https://slack.com/api/channels.create
```

The api is documented [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create)